# How to pass reference to slot in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt

I have two forms in the project: *mainwindow.ui* and *mydialog.ui*.
Each has .hpp and cpp files.
*mainwindow.cpp* file has `QList` object.
I press button on *mainwindow* form and modal *mydialog* form appears.
Then I press button on *mydialog* form and `on_btnCreate_clicked()` runs.

Is it possible to have access to `QList` object in `on_btnCreate_clicked()` slot?

If Yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 void MainWindow::on_btnCreate_clicked() {
     MyDialog dialog;
     dialog.setList(m_qList); // add member setList to your MyDialog class
     dialog.exec();
 }
```

Comment: I'd add new exec() method to MyDialog, whitch gets QList as parameter like this:
`void MyDialog::execWithQList(QList & qlist)
{
    m_qList = qlist;
    exec();
}`

Comment: also it can be passed into MyDialog ctor. there are several ways to do it.

Comment: The problem is that setList() is a handle that runs when MyDialog::on_btnCreate_clicked() occurs. It doesnt invoke from MainWindow::on_btnCreate_clicked()

Comment: ok, add setList to MainWindow, pass MainWindow reference to MyDialog via special member setMainWindowReference and after you can call setList of MainWindow in your MyDialog::on_btnCreate_clicked(): m_mainWindowReference->setList(yourDialogList);

Comment: "pass MainWindow reference to MyDialog via special member" How to do this?

Comment: add new data member MainWindow* m_mainWindow; add new functin setMainWindow(MainWindow* mainWindow) {m_mainWindow=mainWindow;}